# How to get returned value from service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is module and controller code

```
var app = angular.module('apApp',[]);

app.controller('apCtrl', ['$scope','$http','getPopByBranch',function($scope, $http,getPopByBranch)
{   
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';

    console.log(getPopByBranch.test) ;                                                   

}]);

var boot_apApp = document.getElementById('apApp');

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(boot_apApp, ['apApp']);
});
```

This is my service code saved in separate js file

```
angular.module('apApp').factory('getPopByBranch', function($http){

var pops = {};
pops.test = function(){ return "Hello";};
//i want value of second function also
//pops.test = function foo(){ return "Bye";};
return pops;                               
});
```

output in console

```
function(){ return "Hello";}
```

The problem is that i want only hello or some value returned .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function. Update from

```
console.log(getPopByBranch.test);
```

to

```
console.log(getPopByBranch.test());
```

Comment: @MartijnWelker - That can be said only after looking at the markup. Additionally, I believe the OP is able to log the function then OP is able to bootstrap the application. It is just OP is missing on calling a function